# Idle noise on audio-interface when listening trough headphones

Tags: noise, headphones, audio-interfaces, connector, m-audio

When I'm listening trough my native PC audio card (3.5 mm jack), the max volume is much higher and I don't hear any noise.

My recently bought audio-interface M-Track II is worse at this when listening through headphones (I connect trough a 6.3mm TRS adapter). Firstly, the max gain is lower. Also, the idle noise is present, but only at higher gain

Can You explain me why is that and how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried turning the Monitor knob all the way up before gradually turning up the headphone output from 0 to desired level?

Comment: And does it happen only with headphones (i.e. not with the main output connected to powered speakers)? And does it happen regardless of the gain level of the inputs? If the gain is too high (e.g. maximum) you may be hearing the noise from the preamps, not from the headphone output itself...

Comment: What do you mean by "idle noise"? Is it a hissing, like white noise?

Comment: @SimonBosley What is that monitor knob?

Comment: @DarekBuryński Rightmost large dial on the front of the audio interface, should be labelled.

Comment: @SimonBosley Omg thanks, it helped. But why is that, it's so strange that all that crackling goes off because of that solution)? BTW, only ALL THE WAY UP works, nothing between that (while the most noise is when it's turned down to 0)

Comment: @DarekBuryński I think it controls the mix of playback to live instruments when you're tracking live musicians. If you just want playback then you should turn it all the way to the right. I'll add it as the answer so we can close this off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the monitor control all the way should give you only the playback source in the output.

The monitor control is there to set the amount of direct input to playback when you're tracking live musicians.

In your case you just want to hear the playback at 100%, without any noise introduced at the inputs.

Hope this helps!